# How do I queue up an album in the built in iPad Music app?

Tags: ios, ipad, music

I see that I can play individual songs by tapping on them, but I'm trying to figure out how to play albums, and ideally I'd like to do that by queuing them after what's currently playing is complete.

This is on an iPad 2 with the latest iOS update.

Is such a thing possible in the built in app?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ideas that come to mind with this question:

- Make a Playlist

Fairly self-explanatory. Tap the playlists icon on the bottom left hand side of the iPad's Music app (if under iOS 5), then choose `New` in the top right hand, and you can browse through your library and add things to listen too.

When the song completes, you can go back to the playlist, tap on it, and then the first song in the list in order to start playback of the playlist in order.

- You can play an album in full, only if you select if from the 'Album' view.

Note that when you are in the full 'Songs' view, selecting a track will play all tracks after it in alphabetical / listed order. If you choose it from 'Album' view instead, the tracks will play back from that track forward in the album.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can queue within the actual Music app no.

A search on the App Store brought up a few appropriate apps, such as Segue which I have had a little play around with now and seems very appropriate to what you want to do.